# PowerShell: How to increment counter when condition is satisfied

Tags: powershell

My requirement is to go through each directory and sub-directory and find a character after the third dash(-) in a file name and if it is an "A", increment the counter and at the end of the process, write to the host total number of files that met the required condition. How would I do that?

Here is my script:

```
$counter = 0
dir .\ -Recurse | % {
    if (($_.Name.Split("-")[3] -notmatch "[^C]")) {
        $counter++
        write-Host $_.Name.Split("-")[3]
        $counter
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is failing to work for you, please describe how, and what you've done to try to correct the problem. If you received any error messages, including them will also be helpful.

Comment: I don't get any error message but result is not what I expected. Counter keeps increasing and printing no matter what. I want to print the total at the and how total number of files that has an A in the name.

Comment: Show an example of file name and edit your question with the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the counter only once, move it out of the `ForEach-Object`:

```
$counter = 0
dir .\ -Recurse | %{
  if (($_.Name.Split("-")[3] -notmatch "[^C]")) {
    $counter++
    write-Host $_.Name.Split("-")[3]
  }
}
$counter
```

However, I'd propose to not go that route at all. That code is not very nice to read as there's rarely a reason to implement a counter that way (outside maybe of code-golfing).

An easier way is to use the pipeline to get all files matching your condition and then get their count:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.Name.Split('-')[0] -match 'A' }).Count
```

If there are *a lot* of files and memory consumption is an issue, you can use the pipeline to pipe the result to `Measure-Object`:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.Name.Split('-')[0] -match 'A' } |
  Measure-Object).Count
```

Comment: Thanks Joey. I will implement as soon as I get a chance.